# create a circle, divide it into circular sectors and test where a point is located with R

Tags: r, plot, grid, segment

I need your help to create a code that allows me to project points in a circular grid, divided into segments and levels. I'm asking for your help, because I know that this community is full of great people.

What I would like to do is

1. create a circle in a Cartesian plane; the coordinates of its centre point must be x=300 and y=300 and its radius r=300;
2. after constructing the circle, I need to divide it into portions. I need to construct a grid similar to the one you see below, but with 16 segments (with 16 labels, e.g. sector_1 to sector_16) and 5 levels or concentric circles (with 5 labels, e.g. level_1 to level_4 + level_0 for the central circle). So I would need to construct 5 concentric circles and divide the second, third, fourth and fifth into 16 segments. My aim is to obtain a series of regions in which a point could fall;

[image: Circular Grid]

3. after constructing this grid, I need to project in it some points that I have and of which I have the x and y coordinates (e.g. point_1 -> x=286; y=342);

R should return to me in which segment and at which level the point is located.

Please, how can I develop code that allows me to do this?

Any help is so welcome and helpful.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the grid like this:

```r
t <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 1000)

plot(300, 300, xlim = c(0, 600), ylim = c(0, 600))

for(i in 0:4) {
  lines((300 - (i * 60)) * sin(t) + 300, (300 - (i * 60)) * cos(t) + 300)
}

for(i in 0:7) {
  lines(300 * sin(c(i * pi /8, i * pi / 8 + pi)) + 300,
        300 * cos(c(i * pi /8, i * pi / 8 + pi)) + 300)
}
```

[image]

To calculate in which segment the point has landed, you calculate the distance from the centre of the circle and find the whole number of 60s this exceeds

```r
sqrt((x - 300)^2 + (y - 300)^2) %/% 60
```

To find out which segment it belongs in, you need to find its polar angle, which you can get by:

```r
atan2((y - 300), (x - 300))
```

And you can determine which segment this represents by finding the number of `pi/8` it exceeds:

```r
atan2((y - 300), (x - 300)) %/% pi/8
```

Comment: thank you very much allan, you have been very clear and precious! thanks thanks thanks! can I just ask you one last thing? how do I plot my points (e.g. point_1 with coordinates x=286 and y=342 and point_2 with coordinates x=132 and y=201) on the grid and display their position?